# (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Tags: reactjs, firefox, react-redux, react-router, firefox-addon

I was Adding Routing to my project. When I was **fetching my orders** and **outputting the orders** this error is showing in my console.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/the-burger-builder-9bfe3/database/data/orders. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I am using firefox browser and ubuntu for this reactjs. My console is not supporting this data from my firebase . But my data is storing in firebase and its not showing in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method -> 'Authorized domains' section and add your IP Address/localhost/domain name.

Comment: but how i will add my IP Address/localhost/domain name/ . My server is running in localhost:3000.

Comment: Add localhost:3000 then